# Number of active months based on grouped time intervals

Tags: r, date, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I have a table with individuals that perform activities during time intervals (bounded by start and end dates). Some of them have several activities, some others don’t. Sometimes the activities overlap, and sometimes they are separated by a period of inactivity.

I would like to group by individuals and compute the number of months they have been active, no matter the activity.

Here is a small reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("x", "y", "y", "z", "z"),
             activity=c("a1", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2"),
             start=c(as.Date("2017-07-01"), 
                     as.Date("2018-04-01"), as.Date("2018-07-01"), 
                     as.Date("2017-07-01"), as.Date("2018-02-01")),
             end=c(as.Date("2018-07-31"), 
                   as.Date("2018-05-31"), as.Date("2018-07-31"),
                   as.Date("2018-02-28"), as.Date("2018-07-31")))
```

It would look like this on a Gantt chart:
[image]

Does anyone could think of a `data.table` or `dplyr` solution to get the following output?

```
id | active_months
x  |      13
y  |      3
z  |      13
```

Comment: Antoine, shouldn't y be 4 active months? Considering activity started on April 1 and ended on July 31?

Comment: No because the individual is not active during the month of June.

Comment: Got it, let me check my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create monthly sequence between `start` and `end` date and count unique month values for each `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(months = n_distinct(unlist(purrr::map2(start, end, 
                      ~seq(.x, .y, by = 'month')))))

#   id    months
#  <chr>  <int>
#1 x         13
#2 y          3
#3 z         13
```

Comment: Ronak, your code is giving active months as 14 for last ID z and my code gives 4 months for ID y.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this solution does not work in the case of overlapping activities. In my example z is active in february 2018 both with the activity b1 and b2. However, my concern is just knowing how much months individuals have been active over this period of 13 months.

Comment: @Antoine Updated the answer, can you check? @ Karthik corrected the answer as well.